# Java Get first character values for a string

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I have inputs like

> AS23456SDE
>
> MFD324FR

I need to get First Character values like

> AS, MFD

There should *no first two or first 3 characters input can be changed*. Need to get **first characters before a number**.

Thank you.

Edit : This is what I have tried.

```
public static String getPrefix(String serial) {
    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c : serial.toCharArray()){
            if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                break;
            }
            else{
                prefix.append(c);
            }
        }
        return prefix.toString();
}
```

Comment: Convert String into char[] and try using Character.isDigit(string.charAt(no.)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by a simple regex which matches digits and java's [string split function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-). This Regex based approach will be more efficient than the methods using more complicated regexs.

Something as below will work

```
String inp = "ABC345.";
String beginningChars = inp.split("[\\d]+",2)[0];
System.out.println(beginningChars); // only if you want to print.
```

The regex I used `"[\\d]+"` is escaped for java already.

**What it does?**

It matches one or more digits (d). `d` matches digits of any language in unicode, (so it matches japanese and arabian numbers as well)

**What does `String beginningChars = inp.split("[\\d]+",2)[0]` do?**

It applies this regex and separates the string into string arrays where ever a match is found. The `[0]` at the end selects the first result from that array, since you wanted the starting chars.

**What is the second parameter to `.split(regex,int)` which I supplied as 2?**

This is the Limit parameter. This means that the regex will be applied on the string till 1 match is found. Once 1 match is found the string is not processed anymore.

From the Strings javadoc page:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

*This will be efficient if your string is huge.*

**Possible other regex if you want to split only on english numerals**

"[0-9]+"

Comment: @user2473015 : I tested with a few cases, I may have missed something!, could you tell me the input for which this failed so I can try out.

Comment: It returns same string i pass. I tried with AS123  //

public static String getPrefix(String serial) {
        return serial.split("[\\d]+",1)[0];
    }

Comment: @user2473015 : edited and corrected, I made an indexing mistake. Works for 1AS123 (returns "") as well as AS123 (returns "AS")

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice one line solution.  It uses a regex to match the first non numeric characters in the string, and then replaces the input string with this match.

```
public String getFirstLetters(String input) {
    return new String("A" + input).replaceAll("^([^\\d]+)(.*)$", "$1")
                                  .substring(1);
}

System.out.println(getFirstLetters("AS23456SDE"));
System.out.println(getFirstLetters("1AS123"));
```

**Output:**

```
AS
(empty)
```

Comment: If I input 1AS123 this will return same value.

Comment: @user2473015 I updated my answer that it will return an empty string if the input begins with a number (i.e. there are no letters).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution could be like this:

```
public static void main (String[]args) {

    String str = "MFD324FR";
    char[] characters = str.toCharArray();

    for(char c : characters){
        if(Character.isDigit(c))
            break;
        else
            System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like this simple solution.  I like it when methods describe what they are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function to get required output

```
public String getFirstChars(String str){
 int zeroAscii = '0'; int nineAscii = '9'; 
 String result = "";
 for (int i=0; i< str.lenght(); i++){
   int ascii = str.toCharArray()[i];
   if(ascii >= zeroAscii && ascii <= nineAscii){
     result = result + str.toCharArray()[i];
   }else{
     return result;
   }
 }
 return str;

}
```

pass your string as argument

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "MFD324FR";
        int index = 0;
        for (Character i : testString.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(i))
                break;
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println(testString.substring(0, index));

}
```

this prints the first 'n' characters before it encounters a digit (i.e. integer).